# How to cover IOException from method that has InputStream in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mockito, inputstream, ioexception

would like to seek for help on my JUnit testing. On my method, I was able to cover all except the part where IOException needs to be thrown. I have done many workaround on this, but none of it seemed to work.

Here is the method where IOException was not covered on unit test

```
public String GetstrXMLValue(String strXML, String strCriteria) {
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    builder.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_S1, "");
    builder.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_S2, "");

    Document xmlDocument;
    String strValue = "";
    ErrorHandler objErrHdl = new ErrorHandler();
    
    try {
        InputStream objStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(strXML.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        xmlDocument = builder.build(objStream);
            
        XPathFactory xpath = XPathFactory.instance(); 
      
        XPathExpression<Object> expr = xpath.compile(strCriteria);
      
        List<Object> xPathSearchedNodes = expr.evaluate(xmlDocument);
        
        if (xPathSearchedNodes.size() > 0) {
        
            Content content = (Content) xPathSearchedNodes.get(0);
            
            strValue = content.getValue().toString();
        }
        
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
        objErrHdl.LogError(this.getClass().getName(), "GetstrXMLValue", "ERROR RETRIEVING XML VALUES (XML=" + strXML + ";CRITERIA=" + strCriteria + ")", e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        objErrHdl.LogError(this.getClass().getName(), "GetstrXMLValue", "ERROR RETRIEVING XML VALUES (XML=" + strXML + ";CRITERIA=" + strCriteria + ")", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        objErrHdl.LogError(this.getClass().getName(), "GetstrXMLValue", "ERROR RETRIEVING XML VALUES (XML=" + strXML + ";CRITERIA=" + strCriteria + ")", e.toString());
    }
            
    return strValue;
}
```

Here is my JUnit testing

```
@Test
public void testGetstrXMLValueThrowsIOException() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchFieldException {
    OutputStream responseBody = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
            "                <RESULT>\r\n" + 
            "                <SHORT_NAME>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</SHORT_NAME>\r\n" + 
            "                <ID_CODE>9999999999999</ID_CODE>\r\n" + 
            "                </RESULT>";
    
    xmlHandler.XMLGenerateRootResult();
    xmlHandler.GetstrXMLValue(xml, ".//RESULT/ID_CODE/text()");
    try
    {
        InputStream input = XMLHandlerTest.readXML(xml);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        input.close();
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            responseBody.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            
            throw new IOException();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

### You meant: How do I make the test fail if an IOException occurs

By not catching it. The default behaviour of a test case, if it throws an exception, is that the test case is considered failed. Note that `System.out.println(e);` is tossing out a humongous amount of useful info about the error, *AND* means the code will keep going. `e.printStackTrace();`, `LOG.something()` or `System.out.println()` are basically always bugs if you do that in a catch block. Stop doing that. If you can't be bothered to deal with the problem or don't know how, the only correct 'I dunno' code in a catch block is this:

```
catch (Whatever e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e);
}
```

In this case, just remove the try/catch entirely, and your test will properly fail if an IOException occurs.

### You meant: I need to test my method if *IT* throws an IOException; how do I test that it does the right thing?

Well, there's no point, is there? Your method is obviously broken if an IOException happens, because your method will log something and just keep on going. That's rather silly, and I don't think it's useful for me to try to explain to you how to write a unit test that tests that your method returns the arbitrary misleading value and writes a log message. I don't think anybody would actually want that behaviour.

Make your method throw something on error, and you can easily confirm that it does this with junit. Give it its own test method and annotate:

```
@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void testSomething() {
    if (Boolean.TRUE) throw new IOException();
    // this test will _PASS_, because we said
    // it SHOULD throw IOException.
}
```

### You meant: How do I make this method throw IOException?

That's not easily possible unless you kind of ruin your method to make it possible. If you stop catching exceptions and turning them into silly things (a log message and continuing with the code), the code coverage ceases to be an issue. Just get rid of those catch blocks entirely.